# configure RefControl extension using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

i am using [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/refcontrol/) addon with selenium and it starts fine, but how do you go about affecting the settings of addons in selenium?

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.firefox import webdriver

profile = FirefoxProfile('/path/to/profile')  
driver = webdriver.WebDriver(firefox_profile = profile)
driver.get("http://localhost/referer.html")
driver.find_element_by_link_text("go there").click()
```

the problem is that this addon does not do anything unless you configure it first, but there is no documentation, that i can find on this.

Comment: What if you install and configure the extension first, then use that firefox profile with selenium?

Answer (score 2):

General way, as alecxe suggested, "to install and configure the extension first, then use that firefox profile with selenium". This will probably work with any extension.

I also search for configuration in prefs.js (or about:conf) and found out, that it stores the value in "refcontrol.actions" preference. This way you will be able to change the extension behavior in your code. Example:

```
profile = FirefoxProfile('/path/to/profile')  
profile.set_preference("refcontrol.actions", '@DEFAULT=@NORMAL example.com=@3RDPARTY:http://www.referer.com/your/referer');
```